# Why does the Boolean modifier duplicate my mesh cutter and simultaneously combine meshes instead of cutting?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

so the Booelean modifier duplicates the cutter mesh once I press apply and at the same time connects the boolean mesh to the mesh I want to cut from.
Why is this happening?

Best

Comment: Boolean won't delete the object used as cutter. For the connection it may be a bug, you need to tweak the options to see if it will make it work better...

Comment: @George Tsiklauri if sybog64 has answered your question it'd be helpful if you accepted it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean modifier has several modes, reflecting 3 of of the mathematical Boolean operators: AND, OR and AND NOT under the names Intersect, Union and Difference.

In order to use it as a 'Cutter' you would select Difference. It's easiest to see what's going on if the cutter object is set to 'Wire' in the object's Viewport Display.

[image: boolean difference with wiremode on the cutter]

Sometimes, the Fast solver fails and constructs geometry following the cutter. This would happen in the modified state as well. Use the Exact solver (update blender if it is not available) or move your cutter until the overlap is solved correctly.

If you have difference between the modified state and the result after applying, you've most likely applied it out of order or applied something that had Viewport disabled.
Bugs do occur. They are usually solved by restarting blender